# Is there a format for blog posts?

Tags: support, blog

I am wondering if we have to have a certain format when we post on the blog, and if so, what is it? I just want to make sure before I begin posting.

Comment: Hmm... This is a good question. Give me a few minutes (read: hours, days or weeks) to answer this.

Comment: By the way, please wait until after the official announcement before publishing anything on the blog.

Answer (score 6):

When you write blog posts, please keep the following things in mind:

- WordPress supports "categories". These are a little bit like tags. Use them as if they were.
- If you're writing something big, use Read More tags (`<!--more-->`). These prevent people from thinking "it's long" and abandoning it while, if used correctly, enticing them to read further without overwhelming them.
- Use correct English. This doesn't mean you need to change dialect, but it *does* mean:

  - Spell things correctly. You can write "color" or "colour", but don't write "culler".
  - Use correct grammar. This is a little trickier. Use punctuation correctly, use words in the right place, don't confuse homonyms, use "e.g." for examples and "i.e." for clarification, etc.
  - However you spell "television programmes" and "programmes for a performance", it's "computer **program**". You should strive for "progra**mm**ing" and "progra**mm**ed" as well, but this is not neccesary.
  - Above all, *be consistent!* Don't change style or dialect mid-way through a post.
- Make your posts as informative, useful and interesting as possible. We want people to actually *read* our blog, even if they're not experts in the field.
- Cite your claims. Provide references to claims you make (where relevant). You can do this by placing `<sup><a href="#citation-1">[1]</a></sup>` (change the number as appropriate) just after the clause you want to cite, and the following at the end of your post:

  ```
  <hr />
  Citations:
  <p style="font-size: small;">
      <span id="citation-1">[1]: <a href="//example.com/page/">http://example.com/page/</a></span>
  </p>
  ```

  This should be done in raw (HTML) mode to prevent escaping of the markup.

Comment: Thanks for these!  I just went and updated my post with the `more` tag.

Comment: @Aaron I noticed that you have some references at the bottom of your post. Are those sources of information or just related pages?

Comment: Those are sources that I either quoted or summarized.  Ahh, so I should probably go back and use the citation tag?

Comment: @Aaron If you think it would add to the post. :-)