# Sharing knowledge

Tags: discussion, scope

I have recently made a few games for the Sinclair ZX80 with 4K ROM (mostly unexpanded, but some requiring as much as 2K of RAM) - would it be acceptable to share what I know so far about programming and computing on this retro computer here? Or is this not the right sort of place for that sort of retro computing?

Also, you don't have a ZX80 tag. Is the ZX80 not considered a retro computer? Or a Sinclair tag either.

Comment: It is good to see that you are still here on the site.

Answer (score 5):

This, like all StackExchange sites, works in a Q&A format.  Therefore, simply posting what you have done as a question would be frowned upon.

So, I would suggest that you post self-answered questions.  Something along the lines of "*How can I get my game to work on a ZX80?*", wait a short time and post the answer.

Such self-answered questions are acceptable and would definitely be useful for other members of the community.

So, yes, sharing the knowledge that you have is not just acceptable but is welcome.  It is just the manner in which you put it.

As to the tags, there isn't a ZX80 tag because nobody has created it yet.  We don't create tags before there is a question to put them on.  Users can create new tags once they have 150 reputation (on a beta site), but you can always ask the question and request here on Meta that someone create a tag for you.

Comment: I don’t think there’s any need to wait before posting the answer (in fact, the question page allows you to post the answer simultaneously). If someone else has a better answer, they can always post it, regardless of whether there already is an answer... (Ignoring the social aspects of there already being an answer.)

Comment: It’s not as if voting happens so fast here that first-mover gives a huge advantage! It does provide a bit of an advantage but it’s not prohibitive IMO, at least as long as the answer isn’t accepted.

Comment: So if I start with "How do I make a game on a 4K ROM equipped ZX80 with just 1K of RAM" - this would not be too broad a question?

Comment: @ShaunBebbers: I think that would be fine.  I would add some of the issues in the question body.  Good luck with it.

Comment: I don't need luck as I already know most of the answers to the question that I want to ask.

Comment: @ShaunBebbers: I don't doubt that.  I was wishing you well in terms of getting upvotes.

Answer (score 4):

For when knowledge, information or even a good story is on-topic but doesn't fit into the Q&A format, you could create a post on [The Retrocomputing Blog](/tags/blog). Post an answer to [this question](https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/q/223/278) to request an Author account if you want to post anything.

It's a good place to share the process of a project (e.g. thoughts, challenges) or any other related thing that doesn't fit on [main](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/) - interesting things that would probably otherwise be dealt with and forgotten.

Comment: I "worked" for over a decade (of sorts) in the fledgling retro computer market (much more of a scene/community back then) - I can share lots of stories && stuff. It's just a time thing.

Comment: @ShaunBebbers You might be interested in taking a look at [the existing content on the blog](https://retrocomputingblog.wordpress.com/).

Comment: @ShaunBebbers If you're still interested in writing some articles and might have the time at some point in the future, I can set you up with an account.

Comment: I need to be clear what you mean by "retro computing" as it seems to be something different from my understanding of what "retro computing" is. I'm developing a couple of ZX80 games and will post in code review for feedback even though that doesn't seem like the correct place.